# Replace submit button with image

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating feedback page by images, Happy, Satisfied, Neutral, Disappointed etc...

Originally I was asking the user to type/input the feedback, but this was inefficient. The data is going from the form submission to google sheet.

How do I associate every image with its own submit and constant value ?

So if user clicks on Happy image it would click submit --> Happy, click on satisfied image submit --> satisfied

Here is what I did so far.

```
<div class="container">
<form name="SubmitUserFeedback">
    
        <input  type="hidden" name="VeryHappy" value='Very Happy' required>
    
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/img/feedback/100.png" alt="Happy" style="/>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/img/feedback/80.png"  alt="Satisfied"/>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/img/feedback/50.png"  alt="Nuteral"/>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/img/feedback/25.png"  alt="Disappointed"/>
<input type="image" name="submit" src="/img/feedback/0.png"  alt="Very Sad"/>     
    
</form>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    
  const scriptURL = 'SCRIPT URL'
  const form = document.forms['SubmitUserFeedback']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
    
</script>
```

Comment: This is not good for accessibility. Perhaps style a button with a background image instead so you don't lose any accessibility features the button provides?\

Comment: I wanted to edit my comment, I reckon each input needs to be its own form with a submit button so they are more accessible but I haven't created this to test it.

Comment: I need to record the inputs somewhere and cannot connect button to spreadsheet, at least not that I know of.

Comment: Make a separate form for each button/image so your formaction submits the response to the google sheet.